# Turning a stateless C++ function inside out, into a stateful one

Tags: c++, algorithm, refactoring

I have a C++ character-parsing function that was written to run in its own thread. It's designed to make a blocking call each time it requires more data to process and never to return until all data is processed. Something like this:

```
void runParser() {
    while(true /*returns only when EOF encountered*/) {
        //...
        c = getNext();  //blocking call
        //...
             //...
             c = getNext();  //blocking call
             //...
        //...
        c = getNext();  //blocking call
        //...
            //...
                //...
                    c = getNext();  //blocking call
                    //...
                //...
                c = getNext();  //blocking call
            //...
        //...50 more lines of code...
    }
}
```

The function is littered in instances of this blocking call for input which are interpreted differently under a multitude of different scenarios.

I need to turn the functionality inside out. Rather than having a single monolithic function that waits for input, I need a function that I can call synchronously to process each bit of new data when it becomes available. This means the parser code needs to go from being stateless to remembering its state. I need to modify the code as quickly as possible with minimal effort.

My preliminary idea is to modify the function as follows:

1. Replace local variables with static ones (so the function retains state)
2. Replacing blocking calls with a return statement, preceded by an assignment of a 'current code position' variable.
3. When new input is available, call the function again with the new data.
4. The beginning of the function uses a `switch()` and bunch of `goto`s to jump back to its previous position.

Can anyone suggest an alternative that is more elegant, less messy, and perhaps doesn't involve goto? For example, does C++ have anything else remotely useful for implementing these kinds of 'stateful returns'?

Comment: Maybe something like setjmp/longjmp? Other than that, I see no inherent way to keep this pattern. If only C++ had monads...

Comment: There's also a neat boost library for coroutines http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `static`: those are almost global variables in disguise.

There is a microsoft proposal involving the await keyword that makes your change trivial.  But that isn't here yet.

The "mechanical" translation of that proposal to current C++ code looks like your solution, except we make class member state variables, instead of static state variables, and operator().  They also support composition, but you don't need that.

You can replace the switch maintenance with storing the label directly in void pointer pointers and a goto.

Refactoring from the goto solution can be done.  Take each run of code between returns and put it first in a lambda, then into a method.  It can be difficult or impossible or pointless, but refactoring could eventually replace the gotos.  You may end up with a state machine, which is only arguably easier to understand than spagetti goto.

The real clean solution is awaiting for coroutines in some future version of C++; sorry.  You might be able to get ideas from looking into how people implement coroutines today...

Comment: I had never heard of label pointers in C before, but these certainly look useful. (Incidentally, I'm starting to think that the whole reason my 'before' code is arranged the way it is, is so that it *doesn't* resemble a state machine)

Answer (score 0):

To make a stateful function, use a functor. This is an object of a class with an overloaded () operator. You instantiate this object in an initial state, set by the constructor, and during the calls to theObject (), you adapt the state, which as said is kept internally in the object.

Comment: That might be a neat end-result, but doesn't answer my question unless you only read the headline. The problem is how to take a mature block of code and transition it into that form with minimal modification.